# orientdb studio functions not displaying

Tags: function, orientdb

We recently exported all the databases to new set up. Orientdb functions are visible at the backend. i.e. functions are successfully imported but not visible in studio.

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Are you talking about JS functions?

Comment: Hi, I am using v 2.2.29. I am talking about the complete function management system. Neither SQL more JS none of the functions are displaying. Also the OFuncion system class has no record as we see under the schema. But the queries are working fine since functions are loaded as seen from backend.